# Blank item always appear in select tag when binding with database table

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For some reasons, I have a strange issue in my ASP.Net MVC/angularjs view. I am listing users in a hidden select tag, Once I click list to show the select tag, I see the users but there is always a blank item at the beginning of the list??! What makes it more stranger, that blank item disappear once I select any other (non blank) items.

[image]

[image]

[image]

View:

```
<select ng-options='x as (x.fName+" "+x.lName) for x in users' ng-model="uListModel"></select>
```

AngularJS:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetUsers')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.users= response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

MVC Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetSupervisor()
{
    return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                      select new
                      {
                        Id = userObj.Id,
                        fName = userObj.usrFirstName,
                        lName = userObj.usrLastName,                                  
                      })
                      , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                      );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try one of these two solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
<select ng-options='x as (x.fName+" "+x.lName) for x in users' ng-model="uListModel">
       <option value="" selected="selected">Select User</option>
</select>
```

**Solution 2:**

Set initial model value:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetUsers')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.users= response.data;
        $scope.uListModel = $scope.users[0]
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

Or:

```
    <select ng-init="uListModel=users[0]" 
ng-options='x as (x.fName+" "+x.lName) for x in users' ng-model="uListModel"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks Ismail, that was helpful.

Comment: Another question, how I can represents the value of the select tag in ng-options?

Comment: The selected model (value) is uListModel ! that's what you ask for ?